# User control with Active Directory on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp

We have a problem with users downloading applications, installing, playing games, and other such unwelcome activities. Is it possible to use Windows 2003 to control the user's desktops? I've seen it done with 2008 but not sure if 2003 as the abilities as I've not been able to find the options for such controls.

Our users all use Windows XP.

Comment: Are your users local administrators? If "yes", that's the beginning of your problems. You need to resolve that before you implement any other configurations.

Comment: Never though about local users or controlling in that sense. I was thinking it would probably be easier to delete ALL users locally but the Administrator and then setup AD to control the users.

Comment: Oh goodness yes, you almost certainly want local users gone and to manage this in AD. Technically, I suppose you could set a Local Security Policy to do what you want for local users. But I'm pretty confident that is not a best-practice.

Comment: So remove ALL local based users?

Comment: Both local and domain users can be added to a workstation's local `Administrators ` group.  You want to ensure that *only* users that *require* admin access [this should be a short list] are members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure User and Computer settings in Windows 2003 with Group Policy and Group Preferences, just as in Windows 2008. This may solve some of your configuration issues. Going into all of the details of Group Policy and Preferences is beyond the scope of a simple answer, but Google will be your friend here. Also, each version of the Windows client increases the capability of Group Policy, so you will need to be diligent in verifying that you can accomplish what you want in Windows XP.

Group Policy alone won't necessarily solve your problems, at least not without extensive scripting. If you're having problems with programs being installed as a non-admin, you'll likely need to augment Group Policy with other tools. If the problem is people installing programs as local admins, then removing local admins permissions should be your priority before any of this work.

As for games, are you talking about online, or installed? Again, Group Policy won't necessarily solve, say, Flash games. There are other network tools to prevent that.

Depending on how much of a problem this is, you may need to step up to system management tools, such as Kace or Microsoft System Center. Again, beyond the scope of a simple answer, but this should get you started.

Comment: So control options increase based on the client's OS? Like XP will have less options then say Vista or 7? Guess what I am mostly looking for is the ability to just limit a user to running specific installed applications and internet explorer.

Comment: That is correct. I haven't looked at XP in some time, but Group Policy should let you limit what programs run by Computer and/or User.